# Updating JTable Data -- using a AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener, abstracttablemodel

I have been reading the forums extensively and tried numerous methods on how to solve this problem.

**The Problem:**
I made a custom `AbstractTableModel` so I can control the way my data is displayed. It is simply stored in a `String[][]`. It connects to a DB using `JDBC` to populate the initial data. So, when my user (through the `Swing` GUI) searches for a something, behind the scenes I simply construct a query to query the DB and it returns a `ResultSet`. Now, I want to display this new Data on the `JTable`.

**Research:**
I read a lot about listeners and firing updates and things. But I have read and reread them and still do not completely understand them. When I set a new model to the `JTable`, I actually want to KEEP my custom `AbstractTableModel` I created and just update the data, is this possible (maybe with public methods inside `AbstractTableModel` class that I can create)?

**Additional Questions:** Should I be using a listener for this functionality? Do I need to add listeners or observers?

Thanks, I really appreciate it!
Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Research: I read a lot about listeners and firing updates and things.
>   But I have read and reread them and still do not completely understand
>   them. When I set a new model to the JTable, I actually want to KEEP my
>   custom AbstractTableModel I created and just update the data, is this
>   possible (maybe with public methods inside AbstractTableModel class
>   that I can create)?

Yes it's possible.  Basically, you need to either...

1. Provide functionality in your custom table model to add and remove rows or
2. Construct a new instance of the custom table model using the new data

> Additional Questions: Should I be using a listener for this
>   functionality? Do I need to add listeners or observers?

It's difficult to say without context.  I would say, generally no.  In your case it's probably simpler to create a `SwingWorker`, perform the database query and either populate a new table model and return it from the `doInBackground` method or use the `publish`/`process` methods to update the existing model.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your list made sense of the two options I have when dealing with tables. I got it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

> ....so I can control the way my data is displayed

A model is used to store data. The view (JTable) displays the data.

> It is simply stored in a String[][].

There is no need to create a custom TableModel. Just use the DefaultTableModel.

> I actually want to KEEP my custom AbstractTableModel

Use the `setDataVector()` method of the DefaultTableModel

See the [Table From Database Example](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) in the `Get the Code` section.

Comment: The reason I want to keep my AbstractTableModel is because I have a row of check boxes. This functionailyt isn't provided by a DefaultTableModel. So how would you reccomend I handle updating the table rows with this?

Comment: @RichieEpiscopo, yes you can display a row of check boxes in the JTable when using the DefaultTableModel. Again I will stress the model stores the data, the table renders the data. You store Boolean values in the model, then you override the `getColumnClass()` method to return the appropriate class and the appropriated render/editor will be used by the table.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. You also cleared up a few things for me. I got it working now!